# How to fetch instance security group name dynamically via Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-security-group

I made image of source instance and now i had to clone new instance, Thus i hardcoded the security group name of source instance in target instance creation. now I want it to be dynamically. Below is my code:

```
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2',region_name='region') 
    instance = ec2.create_instances( ImageId=image, InstanceType='t2.micro', KeyName='keyName', SecurityGroups=['sgr-ssh-http-public'], MaxCount=1, MinCount=1 )
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Please be more specific. What have you tried so far? Why didn't you upload your code?

Comment: @vishal.k  here is the code
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2',region_name='region')
        instance = ec2.create_instances(
            ImageId=image,
            InstanceType='t2.micro',
            KeyName='keyName',
            SecurityGroups=['sgr-ssh-http-public'],
            MaxCount=1,
            MinCount=1
        )
"SecurityGroups=['sgr-ssh-http-public']" i want this to be dynamic

Comment: This is not how you write code here in stackoverflow. Moreover you should have added the code in your question and not in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the many ways by which you can achieve your desired output.

```
    import boto3
    client = boto3.client('ec2',region_name='ap-south-1')
    response = client.describe_instances()
    for i in response['Reservations']:
       for j in i['Instances']:
          if (j['InstanceId']=="yourparentinstanceid"):
              for k in j['SecurityGroups']:
                sgname=k['GroupId']
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2',region_name='ap-south-1')
    instance = ec2.create_instances( ImageId='imageid', InstanceType='t2.micro', KeyName='keyname',SecurityGroupIds=[sgname], MaxCount=1, MinCount=1,SubnetId='subnetid',)
```